# Find the Nash equilibrium for the given question

Tags: probability, self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

> Consider there are two players in a simultaneous game. Each of them chooses and pays
> integer multiples of one dollar to play the game. The player with the highest bid wins 100
> dollar and the loser gets nothing, though both players lose the amount they bid (e.g., if player
> 1 bids $b_h$ and player 2 bids $b_l$ with $b_h> b_l$, then player 1 gets $(100–b_h)$ and player 2 gets $(–b_l)$ atthe end). Construct a mixed strategy equilibrium (and prove that it is an equilibrium) in which every integer bid bϵ[0,99] has a positive probability.

My answer:

There is no pure strategy Nash equilibrium.

And when I look at the mixed strategy Nash equilibrium, I guess that $P_s = 1/100$ is Nash equilibrium, where $P_s$ is the probability of action of bidding $s= \{0,1,...,99\}$. Because the mixed strategy in this case implies that players are indifferent in choosing the action of bidding.

But, I cannot show my answer in a formal way properly. How can I show its proof?

Comment: What if they both bid the same?

Comment: The question gives no information about that @YJT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose Player 1 chooses uniformly a bid in the set $\{0,\ldots,99\}$ and denote it by $X$.
When Player 2 bids $i$, his payoff is $100\Pr(X< i) -i +50\Pr(X=i)$, where I assumed that when both bid the same, they split the $100$. Since $\Pr(X<i)=\tfrac{i}{100}$, the payoff is $50\Pr(X=i)=0.5$ it is independent of $i$. Thus, Player 2 is indifferent among all the bids.
This is true when player 2 uses this strategy too, so when both chose a number uniformly, neither has a profitable deviation and it's an equilibrium.

Note that the $50$ doesn't really matter. Even if they don't split the $100$ when bid the same but each gets $100$, the indifference holds. However, there might be other pure equilibria in this case (each strategy profile where they bid the same is a pure equilibrium in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand. Well, can you please look at this question as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097009/find-the-pure-strategy-nash-equilibrium-with-3-players